# Get vertical position of scrollbar for a webpage on pageload when the url contains an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am using jQuery's scrollTop() method to get the vertical position of the scroll bar on pageload. I need to get this value after the anchor in the url is executed (ex url: www.domainname.com#foo). I can use the following code and it works in Firefox and IE:

ex url: www.domainname.com#foo

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
         // then a conditional statement based on the scrollTop() value
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#sidenav").height()) { ...
```

But in Safari and Chrome document.ready() seems to execute before the anchor so scrollTop() returns 0 on page load in this scenario. How can I access the scrollTop() value on page load after the anchor executes in Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just want to do something quick-and-dirty like `setTimeout` for however many milliseconds it takes to get it from Chrome or Safari reliably

```
var MAX_CHECKS = 5;             // adjust these values
var WAIT_IN_MILLISECONDS = 100; // however works best
var checks = 0;

function checkScroll() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    // then a conditional statement based on the scrollTop() value
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#sidenav").height()) {
      ...
    }
  } else {
    if (++checks < MAX_CHECKS) {
      // just to make sure, you can try again
      setTimeout(checkScroll, WAIT_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // You can also throw in an if statement here to exclude
  // URLs without # signs, single out WebKit browsers, etc.
  setTimeout(checkScroll, WAIT_IN_MILLISECONDS);
  ...
});
```

Note that you can also use `if ($.browser.webkit)`, although this feature is deprecated and may be moved to a plugin instead of the main jQuery (in favor of feature detection).

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easier way to do this without a timer. But this answer will work. Thanks

Comment: @Greg It's a reasonable hope, for sure, but I don't think there's any event that would fire that you would be able to use. Another option, by the way, is to get the offset height of the anchor element (based on the URL) and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using offset() with the anchor element instead of scrollTop(). This is working great for me in Firefox and Webkit!