# run code after window ready and scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see a difference between FF and Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94 m) in this matter. FF is right (I would say).

when scrolling down a page and hitting then refreshing it, the callback of

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    console.log( $(document).scrollTop() );
});
```

The console should say the amount scrolled after the window was ready, but in Chrome it's always `0`

**How can I show the get the amount of scrollTop in Chrome?**

Comment: _Where_ is the document _when it gets ready_? They could both be right.

Comment: yes, i thought it might be the way each browser is implemented. but what I want to do is so basic there has to be a way running a code on page refresh and detect the amount of scroll at once...

Comment: Actually Chrome _first_ loads, _then_ scrolls. You could try the `load` event. Perhaps Chrome is scrolling on the _load_ event, which could happen _way_ after `DOMReady` has passed.

Comment: the load event doesn't work, just tried

Comment: You could listen to all scroll events for one second after the page load.

Comment: yes I actually already have an event listener for the scroll event which does something, but i want to run a function only ONCE after page refresh

Comment: Try to set a 0ms timeout after the page load, in case Chrome does this: 1) load everything, 2) trigger the 'load' event and 3) scrolls to the pre-refresh location

Comment: yes i've thought about it, but it's not bullet-proof. I can't really know how long it would take Chrome to start the scrolling. honestly I think FF does this best.

Comment: You could think of the _first_ scroll event being the browser's. Otherwise than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Perhaps a chrome-specific event? An attribute of the standard scroll event pointing to its source?

Comment: You could look inside the first scroll event and compare to those from the user to see if it reveals its source

Comment: well, i want the first one that is not triggered by the user, but the browser "remembers" the last position and scrolls there. only that chrome does that after the window ready event, unlike FF

Comment: did you try $(document) instead?

Comment: I fear it's a dead end.. that's how Chrome work. The answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234195/) give alternate way to achieve what you're after, which look fine to me.

Comment: @vsync you could remember the window position in `SessionStorage`. What do you think about it?

Comment: ha, very nice idea Jan, using Session. BUT...it depends. a person can do hard-refresh (ctrl+F5) and not a normal one, and then what..the page will scroll back up.

Answer (score 0):

like some said in the comments, Chrome load the page, and then scroll it down.
Therefor when jQuery event is fired, the scroll is at 0.
You can do some work around like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getScroll() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        ...
    }
    getScroll();

    $(window).scroll(getScroll);
});​
```

So in Chrome `$(window).scroll();` will be fired just after the page is loaded.

EDIT: tested there http://fiddle.jshell.net/azaret/Mt65R/show/light/

Comment: We want to distinguish the browser event from the user events... Your demo does not do that.

Comment: Tested and declared unreliable by OP.

Comment: yeah, a setTimeout is merely a guess that can not be 100% trusted with a small timeout.

Comment: Well for what I heard around chrome, it seems there is not perfect way to achieve what you want. What you could do is to check the `scrollTop` during 50 ms each 5 ms for instance, and when you catch that chrome scrolled you do whatever you want. If you didn't yet  you may check how IE react too, I read some articles that it have some hard time with this too.

I'm not sure you will have a clean way for all browser here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that *document.ready()* in Chrome is executed **before** the browser scrolls down to the previous point and that is why you always get a zero value. A solution is provided here: [Get vertical position of scrollbar for a webpage on pageload when the url contains an anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234195/get-vertical-position-of-scrollbar-for-a-webpage-on-pageload-when-the-url-contai)

Comment: the url doesn't contain anchor because mostly the user just scrolls and then refreshed and the scrollbar "jumps" to the last place it was at.